# node js command line interpreter?

Tags: shell, node.js

1. Is it possible to make Node the CLI interpreter? Can we have 2 terminals with different interpreters?
2. Is there any huge drawback to use Node here?

I know how to list files, but How would we run a program this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set any default shell on `/etc/passwd`. This is a per-user setting, but it may not be wise to give a user node as it's default shell.

I have tried to use emacs as my default shell once some time ago because I use emacs much more than bash itself, but getting in just to have the system updated was a pain.

Also, you are completely discouraged to do this to your root account!

For process execution, a google search threw this:

https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js

Comment: thanks! but isnt possible to get it running as a terminal command interpreter?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. If you execute `node` in a terminal without any files to parse, you land in the REPL. That same REPL as an interactive JS shell is the one you get if you set node as your default shell in `/etc/password`. This will not interpret bash-like commands because it's node.

Comment: Another completely different saying is if you want node in your graphical environment terminal emulator by default, but maybe not in your login TTYs and SSH sessions. Then you can set multiple profiles up in the terminal emulator, each with a different command (node, bash, ...). That is exclusively dependent on your terminal emulation software and doesn't change any user settings. Maybe this is what you want to do.